# App missing 64-bit support

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Xcode 6, Validation passes without any issue, still after submitting for review It states that the binary is invalid, and i get an email saying 'missing 64 bit support'

this is what the mai saidl:

Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

Could somebody please explain this in steps? I find it confusing

help, please...

Comment: Do you believe that you're building with 64-bit support?  Do you have some evidence that 64-bit is there?

Comment: `Build Setting` ->`Architectures` -> `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`

Comment: @Wongzigii I went to build setting, then I was presented with the 'architectures' dropdown, but there isn't anywhere I can edit or change, could you take a screenshot and show me?

Comment: Click `other` and `+`.